# I want to use expect or some other method (other than keygen) for connecting to a remote host

Tags: shell, for-loop, expect

I am harcoding my remote host username and password and need to use it to connect to a remote host from my Mac...I used Expect but its not working...its just prompting for the password...i dont want to use passwordless keygen...

Tried the code below...but its prompting for password

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 20
set pass “ABDFDF”
ssh name@xyz.com
expect ssh name@xyz.com:
send $pass;
interact
```

EXPECTED : connect to the remote host
ACTUAL : name@xyz.com's password:

Comment: You have to be careful about how many arguments you give to the expect command: here you are expecting to see the string "ssh", and when you see it you execute the *command* "name@xyz.com:"

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your password before being prompted for it. Shouldn't there be a

```
 expect Password { send $pass }
```

?

Comment: expect Password { send ${pass}\r }; Tried 
@user1934428 ...but same result

Comment: Also if you send explicitly a carriage return after the password, i.e. `send "$pass\r" }

Comment: @user11458850: And did you spell the "password prompt" exactly in the way (upper/lower case) it comes from ssh?

Comment: i have updated the code like ________      expect "name@xyz.com's password:" ..and also updated like send "$pass\r".....still same result

Comment: I don't see that you have updated your posting with the new commands. Also I notice that you are starting `ssh` in a unusual way. Shouldn't it be `spawn ssh ... `? Also it would help if you would post a transscript of what actually happens when you run the script.

Comment: i actually updated in the actual code...not here...  when i use spawn ..getting this error below ....connect_ii.sh: line 4: spawn: command not found
connect_ii.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
connect_ii.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Then I would make a separate post here on Stackoverflow about this problem. If `spawn` does not work, your `expect` command won't work either, because it doesn't have a stream to monitor. Did you search for connect_ii.sh on your system? Maybe it indeed has a syntax error, as reported.